# MSSQL BCP not recognizing linefeed character (0x0A)

Tags: sql-server

I am using BCP in MSSQL for importing flat file data into table. File has line feed character (0A) as row separator. 
I am using below bcp query to import file
 **bcp dbo.BCPTest in O:\BCPTest\test.txt -c -t| -r 0x0A  -T -h TABLOCK** 
BCP is not able recognize line feed character correctly and importing file incorrectly. Am I giving record separator correctly. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens if you just try to use the default (\n)? Are you sure your linefeeds are actually linefeeds? Try creating a smaller testfile and work with it. Also have you tried using a format file instead?

Comment: @Allan S. Hansan If i use default \n, BCP query is fetching only 184 from 1000 records.

Comment: Open the file in an editor like Notepad++ and show all characters and check if the character at the end of the line is indeed a `LF` character

Comment: @Jaques : I Had checked file if we see in Hex mode record separator is line feed only i.e. 0A

Comment: Try and remove the space between -r and 0x0A

Comment: @Allan S. Hansan : With space or without space between -r and 0x0A result is same.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your BCP command is wrong. Try this :

`bcp dbo.BCPTest in O:\BCPTest\test.txt -c -t "|" -r 0x0A -T -h TABLOCK`